# Unexpected workspace change?

Tags: interface, shortcut

My friend who has only recently downloaded blender has come across a workspace issue. He said he accidentally pressed a button and it has entirely changed his user interface/ Workspace. He can't open, save or do anything with the change.

[image]

This is a full window image!

Comment: please read: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>to exit full screen, or go to view->Toggle full screen

Answer (score -1):

It seems he entered *Rendered Viewport Shading* mode; to close it press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, while your mouse is over the 3D View, or go to the 3D View header (on the bottom, above the Timeline) and on the right side to where it says `Object Mode`, press the button; a list of shading modes will apear, where you can select `Solid` for the default one.