# Accidentally made 3D viewport take up entire screen

Tags: 3d-view

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdPyB.jpg[image]

I hit a button, I'm not sure which one, and everything except the 3D view window disappeared completely. I assume they're just hidden, but outside of the HOTKEY I DON'T KNOW, there's no way to get the menus back and I'm kind of freaking out right now so please, if you know a fix, can you post it?
There's NO menu bar, there's NO timeline, what you see in the screenshot is everything I can access outside of the tools and transform menus with the n and t hotkeys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected workspace change?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21697/unexpected-workspace-change) and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5887/layout-selector-missing/5888#5888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank god, I figured it out. All I had to do was control leftArrow or rightArrow to switch to a different workspace preset and it eventually brought me back to the preset I was on when I messed it up.

Comment: Use Ctrl up_Arrow or Ctrl down_Arrow  to Minimize or maximize the active window...

Comment: shift+ spacebar also maximise and minimise current viewport you work on